# How to Resetting Network Adapter in Windows 10 (without restarting)?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, windows-10

So there is a problem with my Windows laptop. It doesn't connect to my 5G (145) network sometimes (or 2.4G). I have to restart the computer to get it to work.

`netsh winsock reset` does reset the network adapter but it will require a restart. Is there other way to reload the network adapter without restarting the computer?

Comment: +1 I also get this problem sometimes with my openVPN utilities messing up my network configuration. `netsh winsock reset` only works with restart. A hotfix would help a lot if the work you're doing doesn't allow a restart within like the next 8 hours...

Answer (score 8):

I just found that on Windows 7, it can be done with another netsh command. Maybe this also works on Win 10?

First, find out the complete name of your network device you want to cycle:

```
netsh interface show interface
```

This will give you a list of available interfaces in your system like so (excuse the german :D):

```
Verw.-status   Status         Typ              Schnittstellenname
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
Aktiviert      Verbunden      Dediziert        LAN-Verbindung 3
```

Note down the name of the device you want to cycle as you will need it in a second.

Then, enter:

```
netsh interface set interface name="<YOUR-IF-NAME>" admin=DISABLED
```

This will disable the selected network device.
After a few seconds, you should see the device status toggle (in the tray or network device list or wherever..).

Then, enter:

```
netsh interface set interface name="<YOUR-IF-NAME>" admin=ENABLED
```

This will start the interface up again and hopefully, your connection can then be established.

Answer (score 2):

I have a similar issue, and use `Disable` and then `Enable` of the *network adapter*. That takes only 10 seconds total, and solves the issue consistently:

Right-click the icon, chose `Open Network and Sharing Center`, there chose `Change Adapter Settings`, right click, `Disable`, and then right-click `Enable`.

Comment: I tried this already. It works sometimes and other times it doesn't really work. I have to do a full restart to restore the wifi. It doesn't happen prior to Windows 10.

Comment: The above can also be done by entering: `ncpa.cpl` into the Windows cmd line.  This should get you to the *Control Panel\Network and Internet\Network Connections* screen.  Then right click Ethernet and choose Disable.  Then right click again and choose Enable.

Answer (score 1):

I can provide a suggestion. Restart the VPN service under services.msc. I've also tried disabling the network adapter and re-enabling it and using netsh commands. The only thing that did work was a restart at the time. My problem was that occasionally when I put my laptop into sleep and resume from that state, I won't have any access to the internet even though DHCP had given the correct gateway IP, DNS, and host IP address to my machine. I could ping my gateway and other devices on my private network but nothing beyond the WAN connection. When I restarted the VPN service, it immediately connected back online. My particular problem seemed to be a misconfiguration issue or bug associated with my VPN service after coming from a sleep state.